# Read R text into autohotkey AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using AHK's windowSpy, and upon clicking on the R window, none of the text is revealed. Is there a way to read in text from R?
I'm just using vanilla R, no editor. I just downloaded AHK so I should have the most recent version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If the windows spy doesn't show text, then you can't read text *directly*.

There are a few tricks you can do, to read text indirecty, though.

It all depends on why you want to read the text.

If R allows copying to the clipboard, you can simulate the mouse/keyboard movements to capture to copy the text to the clipboard.

If you are looking for specific text, you can use `ImageSearch` to search inside the window.

If you are programming and want to pass results to AHK, you might be able to set the caption text of the form that runs R (which is visible to AHK)

Also, if you run R in a normal **dos window** there is the possibility to connect AHK to that window so that it can see this windows content. This is pretty advanced, see [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/67687-ahkahk-lusing-wsh-to-interact-with-command-line-progs/) for an example.